# Using CMS data in jQuery with granim.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gradient

I'm wanting to use [granim.js](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/) in a current project, however in the docs it is only possible to hard code the colour values into the script. I would however like to make these colour values selectable from my Wordpress CMS, so I'm wondering how I can then pass these values into the granim script?

Would it be possible to replace the hex codes with a Data attribute, and then output the CMS colour values into the DOM for the jquery to reference?

How would I go about achieving this?

Many thanks.

**EXAMPLE JQUERY**

```
var granimInstance = new Granim({
    element: '#canvas-basic',
    name: 'basic-gradient',
    direction: 'left-right',
    opacity: [1, 1],
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
    states : {
        "default-state": {
            gradients: [
                ['#AA076B', '#61045F'] // Can we replace these with data attributes from the DOM?
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

**EXAMPLE HTML**

```
<div id="canvas-basic" data-colour-1="#000000" data-colour-2="#FFFFFF">This div to have gradient background</div>
```

Comment: yes you can do it.can you tell me how you want to implement in wordpress?

Comment: Hi Jinesh. I'll be using the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin to create the fields in Wordpress, which I can then output into my DOM? What further information do you need?

Comment: so you want to implement this things in template right?

Comment: In a template, yes, but then pull some data from the template into jQuery as set out in the example

Comment: can you put that code also in question

Comment: Have added an example div to the question. I have no experience with data-attributes so no idea if this is along the right lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165154/discussion-between-jinesh-and-dungey-140).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement like this:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

var col1=jQuery('#canvas-basic').attr('data-colour-1');
var col2=jQuery('#canvas-basic').attr('data-colour-2');

var granimInstance = new Granim({
    element: '#canvas-basic',
    name: 'basic-gradient',
    direction: 'left-right',
    opacity: [1, 1],
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
    states : {
        "default-state": {
            gradients: [
                [col1, col2] // Can we replace these with data attributes from the DOM?
            ]
        }
    }
});

});
```